# How to run azure pipeline on active LTS and even current releases only?

Tags: node.js, azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I currently have this configuration in my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    node_14_x:
      node_version: 14.x
    node_16_x:
      node_version: 16.x

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: $(node_version)
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

Where v14.x of Node is the active LTS at time of writing and v16.x is the current (even) version of Node at time of writing.

I'd like to refactor it so I don't have to manually update the versions, so I'm looking for something that is like this (NOTE: below doesn't work):

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    node_active_LTS:
      node_version: LTS_VERSION
    node_current:
      node_version: CURRENT_EVEN

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: $(node_version)
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

I keep mentioning *even*, this is because Node.js odd releases (e.g. 15.x) are not intended to be supported for very long. [Read more here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I"m afraid what you wanna do out of the box is not possible, the only way I see this working would be retrieving both LTS_VERSION and CURRENT_EVEN from an external source (a http request for instance) then store the values in a variable and reuse them as an argument to node_version, such as: node_version: $(LTS_VERSION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Bruno.

There is no out-of-box method to do this operation automatically in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

There are two limits:

1. There are no predefined variables related to the nodejs version in the Azure Pipeline.  You couldn't directly use the variable value(e.g. LTS_VERSION and CURRENT_EVEN ) in the node_version field.
2. In the **strategy** field, it does not support running scripts or other commands to get the version of node.js.

Therefore,  no out-of-box method could achieve node.js version automatically in Azure Devops to replace manual settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was starting to question whether it was possible after not being to find any docs 